# ImageButton Selectors don't fire the state_pressed when are clicked in the state_selected

Tags: android

I couldn't find a solution to this yet.

I have a mute/unmute button. I set it up as an ImageButton, with both src and background being selector drawables.

I am displaying
- the "muted" icon when the button is selected
- the "mute" icon when the button is not selected

When the button is clicked I would like to display a yellow background for a fraction of a second
but what I experience is that:
the yellow background appears (by clicking) only when the button is not selected (isSelected=false), and it doesn't appear when the button is selected (isSelected=false)

I don't understand why, but that's what happens!

The yellow background does appear when the button is kept pressed (no matter whether is selected or not), but what I am really interested in is to make it appear when you just click on it without the need of keeping it pressed

any solution?

view.java

```
volumemuteImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.volume_mute);

volumemuteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        volumemuteImageButton.setSelected(!volumemuteImageButton.isSelected());
    }
});
```

layout.xml

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/volume_mute"
   android:layout_width="58dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/img_selector"
   android:background="@drawable/bg_selector" />
```

img_selector.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_muted_pressed"
            android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_muted_pressed"
            android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_muted_default"
            android:state_selected="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_mute_pressed"
            android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_mute_pressed"
            android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_ic_mute_default"
            android:state_selected="false" />
 </selector>
```

bg_selector.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_color_yellow"
            android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/sdmp_color_yellow"
            android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: the imagebutton does not really have an on/off selector so you will have to do that programatically using the onClick ~ (change the drawable). You will need two selector xmls one for on and one for off.. In each of them you will need 2 items (one for pressed and one for not pressed)

Comment: I am actually changing already the selected state programmatically in the onClick. What I can't explain is why the state_pressed get fired by clicking when the button is not selected but it doesn't when is selected

Comment: i notice there is an error in your selector?! `android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true"` appears twice, and `android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="true"` also appears twice

Comment: To be more precise: the pressed_state fires just after the button has been selected (selected=true) from the unselected state, and it doesn't fire after the button has been unselected (selected=false) from the selected state.

Comment: please edit your xml selector to have the 4 combinations of `state_pressed` and `state_selected`

Comment: android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" and
android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="true"
appear only once each actually

Comment: it looks to me that the state_pressed and state_selected combinations are already there: when state_pressed is not specified it is implied it is false

Comment: oh i see.. this is really weird mmm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I SOLVED IT!!!!!

I don't know why, but using the `onTouch` `ACTION_DOWN` would do it, while using the `onClick` the `state_pressed` gets fired only when passing from the `selected=false` to the `selected=true`

how it was before:

```
        volumemuteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setVolumeMute(!volumemuteImageButton.isSelected());
            }
        });
```

how it is now:

```
        volumemuteImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    setVolumeMute(!volumemuteImageButton.isSelected());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```